# In the de-broglie's model of atom, what he said about the path of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

I saw animations in which electron is revolving around the nucleus in a sinusoidal wave like path.
[image: Electron is moving in a wavelike path]
And I saw animation in which a standing wave is shown (no electron)
[image]

So what actually de-broglie proposed? Did he said that electrons move in wave-like path like in gif-1. Or he didn't talked about the motion of electron and simply said that electron behaves like a stationary wave?

Comment: Not sure why you want to regurgitate an old model like that? Today we use Schroedinger to describe atoms.

Comment: @Gert... Just wanted to know how De-broglie and Einstein explained it.

Comment: The atomic model you're referring to is actually Niels Bohr's.

Comment: Yes, but in 1924 de-broglie postulated wave-particle duality for matter and modified Bohr's atomic model. So, was studying his modifications...

Comment: According to me, de-broglie just said that electron behaves like a standing wave, like in second gif (and didn't talk about electron's motion as a particle). And some people interpret it wrong as electron as a particle is moving in wave like path, like in 1st gif. I just want to confirm, am I right?

Comment: Studying old and obsolete models is a waste of time. Study modernity instead! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Hydrogen_atom

Comment: Yes, I am studying about Schrodinger's wave equation now. :]

Comment: @Gert... Can you please answer my another question if you know about it? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162889/in-the-presence-of-external-magnetic-field-energies-of-all-5-orbitals-of-d-subs

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really interested in studying old tat. It belongs in history of physics, not physics itself.